# Binding individual ListView items created in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I have a `ListView` with `ListViewItem`'s created statically in XAML. I want to bind `ListViewItem`'s properties to different properties in my View Model given as a `DataContext` for `ListView`. But my code does not work:

```
<ListView AlternationCount="2" Name="listView">        
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Binding.TargetUpdated="TargetUpdated" Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Units}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding About}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

    <l:PropertyItem Title="title" Value="{Binding Path=DeviceCode}" Units="units" About="about"/>
    <l:PropertyItem Title="title" Value="{Binding Path=VendorName}" Units="units" About="about"/>
    <l:PropertyItem Title="title" Value="{Binding Path=Version}" Units="units" About="about"/>
</ListView>
```

Where NumericItem is:

```
internal class PropertyItem : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(String), typeof(PropertyItem), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(String), typeof(PropertyItem), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UnitsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Units", typeof(String), typeof(PropertyItem), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AboutProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("About", typeof(String), typeof(PropertyItem), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));



    public String Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this.GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public String Title
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this.GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public String Units
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this.GetValue(UnitsProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(UnitsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public String About
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this.GetValue(AboutProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(AboutProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! My `PropertyItem` class derived from `DependencyObject` which in turn  does not contain property `DataContext`. That's why the binding does not work. You need to derive from the one who has `DataContext` property, for example `FrameworkElement` and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Try using these `Binding`s:

```
<l:PropertyItem Title="title" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeviceCode, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Units="units" 
    About="about" />
<l:PropertyItem Title="title" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.VendorName, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Units="units"
    About="about"/>
<l:PropertyItem Title="title" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Version, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Units="units" 
    About="about"/>
```

Here, we're binding to the `DataContext` of the parent of type `ListView`... I believe that's what you were after.

Comment: It does not work until I inherit `PropertyItem` class from `FrameworkElement`. When i do this it works. But then it also works with a simpler `Value={Binding Path=DeviceCode}`.